# Typescript: Omit property from a generic interface

Tags: typescript, interface, typescript-typings, extends, typescript-generics

I am trying to create an interface that omits a property from the given type. To do so, I used `Omit` which results in Type so it is wrong by its definition. However, if it was not a generic interface it worked perfectly.

Consider the following sample.

```js
interface IBaseType {
  prop1: number;
  prop2: string;
  match: boolean;
}

interface OmitMatchNoGeneric extends Omit<IBaseType, "match"> {}

interface OmitMatch<T extends { match: any }> extends Omit<T, "match"> {}

function test(genericArg: OmitMatch<IBaseType>, nonGenericArg: OmitMatchNoGeneric) {
  nonGenericArg.prop1 = 5; // the properties are suggested
  genericArg.prop1 = 5; // intelliSense fails to list the properties
}
```

In this example, the intelliSense of VSCode shows the list of properties for the non-generic argument but it fails to do it for the generic one. The generic argument is being treated as an object of type any.

My main concern is that if I should not use `Omit` what else can I use? And If I wanted to implement it with types rather than interfaces how could I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TypeScript gives you an error on your generic interface:

> An interface can only extend an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members.

That's why it doesn't work. (See the error [on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICE4GcIBUCeADigN4BQyyhUA9oQIwBcyIArgLYBG0A3BVbUIAmZljBRQAcz6V2cMAgAWzTjRoAbCHBB8AvmTKhIsRCgDy7YGACy8pQDkaAcQghowBMggAPSCAAmWMgWVgA8GNh4RBAANMgARHIKivEAfMgk+obg0PBIwZY2doqhuF6+roEZyElKzNr4yLrpPn5VIWClcYnFaRlZMKwgCGDANCDIkGIAFJKu7ggAglCSzB22yeGYOATEqXEg4y5uEksra4UbDs7zpwCUGfyHIMcLy5IAdNR09MgAvMgAKw8ZAAelBk0UKG+xCgowgQTgUBQWFYkjmYgg-n4cxOHneX0EvwBwLBEKMEHU6mAAGVXDhkPBgOogmAaMhqWJIdDBNB4VgyLogA).)

You can use a type instead:

```
type OmitMatch<T extends { match: any }> = Omit<T, "match">;
```

That works correctly. ([On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICE4GcIBUCeADigN4BQyyhUA9oQIwBcyIArgLYBG0A3BVbUIAmZljBRQAcz6V2cMAgAWzTjRoAbCHBB8AvmTKhIsRCgDy7YGACy8pQDkaAcQghowBMggAPSCAAmWMgWVgA8GNh4RBAANMgARHIKivEAfMgk+mRg0cGWNnaKobhevq6BGchJSsza+Mi66QC8eWG4cYmFaXxkMKwgCGDANCDIkGIAFJKu7ggAglCSzCEFyeGYOATEqXEgIy5uEvOLy-m2yY4HswCUGfx7IFdHC5IAdNR09MgtAKw8yAB6AFjRQoD7EKBDCBBOBQFBYViSaZiCD+fjTQ4eF7vQRfX7-IHIIwQdTqYAAZVcOGQ8GA6iCYBoyDJYhBYME0ChWDIuiAA).)

Comment: This is a good example